# For Testing what to Write for constant name in struts.xml file

Tags: struts2

I am Using Struts 2 framework for my project, For Development mode i am using `<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />`
 in struts.xml  file, So my Development is completed so i need to give my project for Testing so what to change for constant name in Struts.xml for Testing (UIT), Its not in Production its in between Development and Production, please any have any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `devMode` is only there to make developer life easy by providing insight about the flow as well help you to reload your config of each request so that things can be smooth.

I believe that there is not going any changes on the QA and it do not make any sense to put dev mode there.

you have 2 options here

1. Comment out that line from your XML
2. If you are using any integration/build tool like `Jenkins` you can have property/conf file based on the profile

Comment: Yeah, just turn devMode off for QA and production.